# Time-driven script fails to run in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, filtering

I would like to create a time-driven script which runs every 6 hours to update the existing filter on a specific column ("J" in "Overview" tab - excluding rows set as "Archived", "Cancelled" and "Excluded") but it's not been possible so far.

My current script is:

```
function Test1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues(['Archived', 'Cancelled', 'Excluded'])
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(10, criteria);
};
```

This works just fine when run manually, but as soon as I add a trigger to that script using the settings in the Apps Scripts you can see in the attached screenshot, I start receiving failure notifications stating "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setColumnFilterCriteria')".

[Settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnyrR.png)

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q3S9dpcomXOO9pE5irvFMSPnWfoK0DsXU3DG6c4QkwA/edit?usp=sharing) you can find an editable copy of my spreadsheet.

I think this might have something to do with the fact that this spreadsheet includes several tabs and I am not specifying on which tab this filter should be updated. Is it possible?

Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Other script option:

```
function FilteredStatus2() {
  var col = 10;
  var filter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getFilter();
  var criteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(col);
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(col, criteria);
}
```

Both of them work when run manually, but fail when sing the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, when you want to run your script with the time-driven trigger, please give the specific sheet instead of the active sheet. Because, when the active sheet is used with the time-driven trigger, the 1st tab is used. When I saw your Spreadsheet, it seems that "Overview" sheet is 2nd tab. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- And, in your script, when the basic filter is not existing, an error occurs.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Test1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Overview");
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(['Archived', 'Cancelled', 'Excluded'])
    .build();
  var filter = sheet.getFilter() || sheet.getRange("J:J").createFilter();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(10, criteria);
}
```

#### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [createFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createFilter())

Answer (score 1):

Yes, get active won't be able to determine which tab you're addressing the code when closed. I suggest you change it to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')` adapting to your actual tab name